# set an imageview over another imageview in different layouts

Tags: java, android, android-layout, imageview

I'm working on a board game and I have this architecture for my views

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <GridLayout>
     <!--ImageViews here-->
    </GridLayout>

      <LinearLayout>
       <!--ImageViews here-->
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

the grid view here is my board and the linear is my stones(representing the player) so my questuion is how can ImageView from linear layout set on top of imageView in the gridLayout in run time that is.

[image: tis is part of my view]

each square represent a cell in my board I figured out where to put my stone when I rolled the dice but how to display this and actually move my stone to that specific cell is what holding me back.

Comment: Not sure of understanding your question. An image showing what you want to achieve would be great

Comment: I edited my question and added an image

Answer (score 0):

Try using attribute: (`android:layout_gravity="top"`) on the images on the linear layout.

Comment: I'm not this will help me since they are not at the same location

Comment: Now you edit with an image of what you are trying to achieve, It's more clear, if you want to move programmatically the stones, you can use params to send it to specific position once you rolled the dice, use: AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams param = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(int width, int height, int x, int y)

Comment: hmmmm this is actually a good idea and since I already know the cell it landed on I can theoretically speaking easily trace it current location...just thinking out loud here. I'll try it out thanks

Comment: Thanks I think your answer is the best for me, if you want you can post it and I'll mark it as best answer

Comment: OK now it's telling me that  AbsoluteLayout is deprecated as of API 3 and now I can either use FrameLayout or RelativeLayout so I'm going to search further into this and post what I'll find, wish me luck!

Comment: FrameLayout will be the best option I think, because you need to make the stone to be on top of the board image, easier to achieve with that...

Comment: Yes and it is also true for the RelativeLayout, now I'm feeling confused on how to arrange the layouts inside the FrameLayout, I don't think that I can use GridLayout now and I should put all the images inside the FrameLayout...I don't know :/